# How do I swap chars of a whole sentence with user input in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, chars

I want to take input from user in

```
char input[200];
```

Then I want to swap each character of that input according to

```
a='y'; b='b'; c='j'; d='m'; e='x'; f='f'; g='w'; h='i';
i='v'; j='c'; k='l'; l='u'; m='t'; n='a'; o='k'; p='h';
q='d'; r='p'; s='s'; t='n'; u='z'; v='q'; w='e'; x='r';
y='o'; z='g';
```

For example if the input is

```
hello
```

The output will be

```
ixuuk
```

I want to code in C++ using for loops and arrays.

Comment: The input can also have white-spaces in it.

Comment: Have you searched for a solution yourself first?

Comment: switch/case, use char values to address a lookup-table, if/else ladder with far too many rungs. Other stuff.

Comment: @KABoissonneault Yes I've searched for the solution but couldn't get a clue at all.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a lookup array:

```
char output = conversion[input_char];
```

You can simplify the array to 26 letters by using some arithmetic:

```
char output = conversion[input_char - 'a'];
```

The expression `input_char - 'a'` makes the letter `a` refer to the first slot in the `conversion` array.

Here's an example of the array:

```
static const char conversion[] =
{'b', 'y', 'c', 'k', 'f', /*...*/, 'a'};
```

Using the above code, if input is `a`, the output will be `b`.  For input of `b`, the output will be `y`, and so on.

No need to swap.  Remember that swapping changes values.  I believe you want *conversion* or *translation* instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it could be done

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    std::pair<const char *, const char *> cipher =
    {
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",   
        "ybjmxfwivclutakhdpsnzqerog"    
    };

    const size_t N = 200;
    char input[N];
    input[0] = '\0';

    std::cin.getline( input, sizeof( input ) );

    std::cout << '\"' << input << '\"' << std::endl;

    for ( char *p = input; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( const char *q = std::strchr( cipher.first, *p ) )
        {
            *p = cipher.second[q - cipher.first];
        }
    }

    std::cout << '\"' << input << '\"' << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"Hello"
"Hxuuk"
```

You could also use functions `tolower` or `toupper` to convert initially characters of the source string to some case.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/7arano
I got the idea but stuck on a line of code. Please see the screenshot from above link and response.
Regards

Comment: @Asad Jamal Malik I am sorry but I do not look through screen shots.

Comment: Okay well, it is saying 
[Error] in C++ 98 'cipher' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'

Comment: @Asad Jamal Malik It might be that you have an old compiler. In the definition of cipher replace braces with parentheses like this 
    std::pair<const char *, const char *> cipher
    (
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",   
        "ybjmxfwivclutakhdpsnzqerog"    
    ); Notice that the assignment operator is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <utility>

int main() 
{
    std::pair<const char *, const char *> 

cipher ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",   
        "ybjmxfwivclutakhdpsnzqerog");



    const size_t N = 200;
    char input[N];
    input[0] = '\0';

    std::cin.getline( input, sizeof( input ) );

    std::cout << '\"' << input << '\"' << std::endl;

    for ( char *p = input; *p; ++p )
    {
        if ( const char *q = std::strchr( cipher.first, *p ) )
        {
            *p = cipher.second[q - cipher.first];
        }
    }

    std::cout << '\"' << input << '\"' << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Special thanks to @Vlad from Moscow

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use the nested loop.
create an array of strings having all the alphabets.
then create another array of strings having all the characters you want to change with the alphabets in the same order of the alphabets.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        string alphabets="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" , 
        cipher="ybjmxfwivclutakhdpsnzqerog" , word , newword="" ;
        cin>>word;
        newword=word;
        for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<26;j++)
            {
                if(word[i]==alphabets[j])
                {
                    newword[i]=cipher[j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<newword;
        return 0;
    }
```